# Is there a way to add traceability of source file in fmus?

Tags: modelica, fmi

When a developer generates an fmu of  a model from the working package (say Library.Package.ForFMUExport.MyModel), the downstream users can check the source model information(Library_Package_ForFMUExport_MyModel), time of generation, tool it was generated form etc. from ModelDescription.xml.

However, the source Modelica models do get updated in repositories and there could be multiple developers with dev branches from which fmu can be generated, and these fmus can get shared between other users/teams. Now, if the downstream user wants to trace back to the original Modelica file, it is hard to track the right version from the information in xml file. Has anyone figured out a solution or best practice to handle this or add traceability in fmus?

This may not have a standard solution, but I wanted to check if there are workarounds or processes the FMI user community is been utilizing to trace right version of the source model. (or maybe there is a standard solution that I am not aware of)

Answer (score 3):

This might be even up to your Modelica library development workflow. If you use proper Modelica library versioning, some/many FMU exporting tools include the Modelica library version as version meta data in the FMI model description. Of course, the exporting tools could even add the revision (and status) from your source code versioning system there. But I have not yet seen it.

Comment: I haven't seen this neither, but if could be realized with standardized or tool-specific annotations in the modelDescription.xml, or by a layered standard and putting meta-information (or even the Modelica Library from wich the FMU was created :-) ) in the /extra directory of the FMU

Answer (score 1):

In theory, <VendorAnnotations> field in modelDescription.xml, or resources/, documentation/ folder can be used to capture metadata of source modelica files. This is entirely up to FMU vendor/exporter who generated the FMU file.